# Upload Video to Youtube with c# Asp .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, youtube

I got this error bellow, after test upload video to YouTube

```
{"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}
```

I don't know what wrong with my code...

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("VideoToYoutube", "AIzaSyBiXxL5nS6IjYRGJUhDdaYdWGqAGwOvD8A");

            YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

            Video newVideo = new Video();

            newVideo.Title = "Teste";
            newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("teste", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
            newVideo.Keywords = "Teste";
            newVideo.Description = "Teste";
            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
            newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("teste, teste",
              YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));

            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = new GeoRssWhere(37, -122);


            newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("C:\\Users\\tadriano\\Documents\\streaming\\mov_bbb.mp4", "video/mp4");

                var createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);

            return View();
        }
```

I have added *localhost*, 127.0.0.1 and * as accepted HTTP referrers in my configuration.

Can Anybody help me?

Comment: Have you logged in the user via the API before you try? A 401 is just telling you that the site doesn't know who you are, so it won't fulfil your request. The API key is just there so the API itself knows who is making the call.

Comment: I logged before I tried and now I re-create and nothing :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this with code bellow and created one Api key OAuth 2 with application type outher.

```
public static Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService AuthenticateOaut(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName)
        {

            string[] scopes = new string[] { Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,  // view and manage your YouTube account
                                             Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl,
                                             Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner,
                                             Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit,
                                             Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly,
                                             Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload};

            try
            {
                // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
                UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                             , scopes
                                                                                             , userName
                                                                                             , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                             , new FileDataStore("Daimto.YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;

                Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService service = new Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService(new Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Web client 1",

                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                return null;

            }

        }
```